How to Interpret "PCIE: Target abort, signature" Kernel Messages on Tegra TK1 Board
I’m working on a Tegra TK1 board using the Xillybus driver to communicate with an FPGA over PCIe. The board also has a second PCIe connection to communicate with another device.
During boot-up, I load the Xillybus drivers and run my PCIe applications. However, one of my applications enters a standstill condition, and I suspect it might be related to these kernel messages I’m seeing:
[   20.929042] PCIE: Target abort, signature: 00101f01  
[   20.933937] PCIE: Target abort, signature: 00100001  
[   20.938827] PCIE: Target abort, signature: 00100b01  
[   20.943715] PCIE: Target abort, signature: 00101c01

I’m trying to understand what these "Target abort" messages mean and how to decipher the signature values (e.g., 00101f01). I think this might help me debug the issue with the application.
Here’s what I’ve looked into so far:

I’ve checked the BAR (Base Address Registers) mappings using lspci, and they appear correct.
I’ve consulted the Xillybus documentation, but it doesn’t provide specifics about these kernel logs.
I suspect the messages are related to the PCIe host controller or hardware diagnostics on the Tegra TK1, but I’m unsure how to decode these "signature" values.

Can anyone explain what these "Target abort" messages indicate, how to interpret the signature values, or provide guidance on debugging this issue?

It indicates that a non-posted Request was sent to the device, and it responded with a Completion that had the Status field set to "Completer Abort", which indicates that the error is permanent and the request should not be retried because the answer will not be different.
So, the PCIe implementation on the FPGA reported an error, likely because the internal bus refused to decode the address. My expectation is that the host side works as intended, and this is an issue with your HDL.
